# how to start flutter project with android studio?

Tags: android, flutter

i wanted to start a flutter project but after i start android studio i get an different [menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DuREG.png) then what i saw (like [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzsXL.png)). and after that, when i start the flutter project, it is different too as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOQFN.png). idk if it effects the outcome, but I dont know how to start a project right with these :(

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

here is new flutter project in the middle

[image: new flutter project]

then choose Flutter

[image]

Comment: @kszunet I updated my answer see the image for next step